# Can't connect to MariaDB using JDBC, mysql utils succeed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc, mariadb

I use JDBC and Spring Boot 2.2.2 to connect to a MariaDB instance. The login fails with this message:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Could not
>   connect to
>   address=(host=server.company.domain)(port=3306)(type=master) : Access
>   denied for user 'user'@'server.company.domain' (using password:
>   YES)

When I run `mysqldump -u"user" -p"password" -h server.company.domain dbname` this works just fine !

- Both the dump and the Spring Boot application are run from the same machine (the database server itself)
- user and password used are identical
- there are no special characters in the password or the user (only lower/uppcase characters and digits)
- the jdbc connection string looks like this: `jdbc:mariadb://server.company.domain:3306/dbname`
- I already tried to use `localhost` instead of the server name
- when I change jdbc url, user and password the same application is able log in to my development mariaDB

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are having trouble with MariaDB, not spring-boot itself.
I suggest you to follow this links: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/, and come back if it didn't solve your problem, with what you tried, and what didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a short `SHOW GRANTS;` via the `mysql` command which is able to connect to the database. The output gave me this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'nonono' REQUIRE SSL WITH GRANT OPTION
```

The relevant part is `REQUIRE SSL`: connections to that server need to be done encrypted.

When I checked the files in `/etc/my.cnf.d/` I found a file containing (amongst others) these lines:

```
[server]
ssl=1
ssl-cert=/path/to/certificate/cert.pem
```

By googling a bit I found [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-tls-ssl-with-mariadb-java-connector/) link which describes how to set the JDBC driver to use ssl. It also explains to you why you perhaps should think twice before setting `trustServerCertificate` to `true`.

My `spring.datasource.url` now looks like this:

```
jdbc:mariadb://server.company.domain:3306/dbname?useSSL=true&trustServerCertificate=true&serverSslCert=/path/to/certificate/cert.pem
```

To put it short: `Access denied for user` doesn't tell the complete story. It makes you think that your password might be wrong but you are denied for other reasons.